# using a class method beside a while loop in c#

Tags: c#, class, methods, static

I am trying to use a while loop when using a public static class method. 
I don't know where to break the loops (while and foreach). 
the target is, prompting the user to enter a correct format of his name which contains all letters.

```
namespace Project1
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public string familyName;
        public int age;
        public static int numberOfStudents;

        public static void IsAllLetter(string name)
        {
            while (true)
            {    
                foreach (char c in name)
                {
                    if (!char.IsLetter(c) || name == null)
                    {
                        break;    
                    }    
                }

                Console.WriteLine("name and family name must contain letters");
                Console.WriteLine("please try again");        
            }        
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // get the name 
            Student student1 = new Student();
            Console.WriteLine("name of the student?");
            student1.name = Console.ReadLine();
            Student.IsAllLetter(student1.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's extract *method*, name *validation*:

```
using System.Linq;

... 

// Simplest, some names like 
// "Charles de Batz de Castelmore d'Artagnan" 
// does not pass
private static bool IsValidName(string value) {
  return
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) &&              // value can't be null or "" 
     value.All(letter => char.IsLetter(letter)); // All letters validation
}
```

Then we can implement a name input:

```
private static string ReadName(string title) {
  while (true) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title)) 
      Console.WriteLine(title);

    // .Trim() - let be nice and tolerate leading / trailing whitespaces
    string name = Console.ReadLine().Trim(); 

    if (IsValidName(name))
      return name;

    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the name is not valid. Please, try again");
  }
}
```

Finally, you can just *use* these methods in your business logic without delving into validation details:

```
Student student1 = new Student();
student1.name = ReadName("name of the student?");
```

Comment: Thank you!
but to be honest, I dont understand from your code. it is a bit advanced for me. I am a beginner and I have just started to code. For instance, why "private" static and not "public" ?! and, what is this => ?!

Comment: @far: well `=>` is just a syntax sugar, let' rewrite it with good old `return`, as for `private` instead of `public` - both extracted methods are *private affairs* of `Student` class (when his / her `name` is in the *public domain*), that's why I haven't exposed them as `public`

Answer (score 0):

You need only a single loop that iterates the characters in your string and return false if any "wrong" character was found:

```
public static bool IsAllLetter(string name)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        return false;
    foreach (char c in name)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetter(c) || name == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Than call that method in a loop:

```
string name;
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("name of the student?");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    if(IsAllLetter(name) break;
}
```

Now you have a name which you can assign to your `Student`:

```
var s = new Student { Name = name };
```

Comment: tnx. So you use 2 loops, one in class and the other in main(), right? the other questions is, naming a method "public static void" can we use "return" ? cause it is void, am I right?

Comment: @far Yeap, both your statements are correct. I set the method to return-type `bool`.